# What does command rm -f -- would do?

Tags: linux, rm

I am trying to understand a command it runs this remove after `-execdir` flag.

`find /a/directory type -f -execdir rm -f -- {} \;`

I am trying to understand what the `--` symbols after rm -f signify ?

Comment: It signals the end of the options and beginning of the filenames. This is useful in case the filenames begin with `-` so it looks like an option.

Comment: This is documented in the `rm` man page.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: It's also a standard feature of most Unix commands.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean